# Hide skipped test console output while using `rails test`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I checked `rails test -h` but I do not see an option to suppress output for skipped tests.  I have a few that need to be skipped and it's hard to wade through the output.  I really only want to see the failures, to be honest, and then a summary at the bottom.

### how I am skipping/passing a test:

Am simply adding the:

```
test "my broken test" do
    skip("I know this test is broken, ignore it for now.")
do
```

### what I am seeing:

In the console output, each *skipped* test is output in the same way an *error* would be (only it's marked as `SKIP`).  The summary is really all I want to see

```
1358 tests, 28 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 1340 skips
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by skipped tests? Do you mean "passed" tests?

Comment: The standard output for a passed test is just a dot isn't it? I'm not sure what output you are trying to suppress, unless it's content your code/tests are producing. In any event, you could try using or making your own reporter - https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters

Comment: @mahemoff - see above, added more details to the original question

Comment: I didn't know that's a thing. Looking at the source, it just raises a special exception, which presumably the framework catches and discards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an official way, but I can think of two workarounds.

One would be to write [a custom reporter](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters).

The other would be to make your own skip function in TestCase (in `test/test_helper.rb`), something like this:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def skip!(message=nil)
    Rails.logger.warn "Skipping #{caller[1]}#{message}" # output caller line
  end

end
```

Then you can simply call this and return in a one-liner:

```
class SomeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "do something" do
    return skip!("I can't do something right now ")
  end

end
```

This won't register as a skip in the count obviously, you'd have to check through minitest to see how to do that. It will just register as a passed test. However, you'll be able to detect all skips by grepping the log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the minitest-reporters gem you can explicitly supress skipped tests:

```rb
Minitest::Reporters.use!([
  Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new(detailed_skip: false),
])
```